# What am I doing Wrong? HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the alert `clear` when I press the button clear. But I want it on the way that the button sets `q = 11`, then is `q < 12` and it will alert `clear`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        var q = 13
        if(q < 12) {
            alert("clear");
            var q = 13;
        }
        </script>
            <button onclick="var q = 11">clear</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tend to avoid questions with titles like this.

Comment: 1. You are defining a new 'var q' each time.  You should have a `function(q)` and pass the variable to it.

Comment: You mean to either: Poll for when var q is changed, or call a method when you click the button (better)

Comment: if statements is always executed when the condition is true

Comment: You should learn about JavaScript. It's obvious from your question you have little to no understanding about it, and a book or online course would be able to help you with basic questions like this.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: So many dislikes, never seen so many!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how this code will be executed. As the page loads, once the browser encounters a `<script>` element with code not contained (i.e., within a function), it will execute that script.

So, when your page loads, it looks at your `<script>` block and:

1. Sets the variable `q` to 13.
2. Compares `q` to `12` using the less than (`<`) comparator.
3. Since the above conditional is false, it will not step into the brackets.

Your button sets `q` to 11, but that is irrelevant at that point in the code, because it no longer checks the conditional. Use Javascript functions to achieve the functionality you desire:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function compare(q) {
            if(q < 12) {
                alert("clear");
            }
        </script>

        <button onclick="compare(11)">clear</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry @FrédéricHamidi didn't mean to step on your toes with that edit! I rolled back to your version.

Comment: No problem at all, the only important thing is that the function names are consistent now. Either of the two names would do :)